# Error With Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am using the date/time picker from Eonasden that you can find here. [Date Time Picker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

I am using HTML from the example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class='well'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It displays the icon fine, but not the calendar drop down. My head script is:

```
<link href="view/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="view/dist/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.0.1-p7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="view/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="view/dist/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.0.1-p7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

$(function() {

  $( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });

});
```

I receive a console error of "Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined" Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? It seems to work fine on his sample page.

Comment: Did you download moment.js and reference it from your code?

Comment: You must also add the 'momentjs-rails' gem, and then modify your application.js file, to require it before the "bootstrap-datetimepicker" entry.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to the examples, you need to include this to..

http://momentjs.com/

It has to be after `bootstrap.js`, but before the `datetimepickerjs` like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/moment-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

It shows it on the GitHub readme..

> "Datetimepicker requires moment.js."

Comment: I did not see that in the GitHub build. Where did you find that? I did add it an still no luck though.

Comment: I do see that now. However that still did not fix the issue. I no longer get any errors in the console, but still no drop down.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the order of the scripts. Works great now. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

**Simple solution**

Once even I got the same error. I was able to fix that by including the content delivery network or content distribution network (CDN) link of the script file.

Try the code below:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>
```

> **Include the above code before adding-in the
>   bootstrap-datetimepicker.js**

Answer (score -1):

I found wrapping your code in

```
$( document ).ajaxStop( function() {});
```

fixed it for me