# Django 2.0 ModelForm dateField not displaying as a widget

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a fairly simple model form with a 'date_of_birth' input value of type datefield(). For whatever reason, I cannot get it to display as a widget and can only get it to display as a text input.

Here is my form code:
    from django import forms
    from . import models
    from django.contrib.admin import widgets

```
class CreateNewPatient(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.PatientInfo
        fields = ['first_name', 'nickname','last_name',
            'date_of_birth', 'school_grade', 'sex', 'school']
```

Here is my model:

```
class PatientInfo(models.Model):
    #first name, last name,nickname, and date of birth
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    school_grade = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
```

Here is my template. It is based on a base template and is using the bootstrap4 plugin:

```
{% block content %}
<!--Form Container-->
<div class="container">
    <form  action="{% url 'patientRecords:new_patient' %}" method="post" 
         class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}
        {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Like I said, the form displays the date of birth field as a text box. How do I make it display as the normal django date widget with bootstrap styling?

Comment: Text input is the input widget for a date field.  The date picker that is in the admin is a javascript add on.  You can go with the text input, add some javascript to make a date picker widget, or there is an option to split the date field into three fields for month, day, and year.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148125/how-to-use-the-bootstrap-datepicker-in-django-app

Comment: You should consider using third libraries such as **Boostrap datepicker** as @Walucas said

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
class Meta:
    model = CreateNewPatient
    fields = ['first_name', 'nickname','last_name',
        'date_of_birth', 'school_grade', 'sex', 'school']
    widgets = {
        'date_of_birth': forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%Y'), attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Select a date', 'type':'date'}),
    }
```

That's how I got mine to work. Hope it helps!

should look something like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxnZh.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
widgets = {
    'date_of_birth': forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'), attrs={'firstDay': 1, 'pattern=': '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', 'lang': 'pl', 'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd', 'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

the most important thing was:
`'type':'date'` in attrs

Answer (score 1):

Too complicated. The solution is this one:

```
widgets = {
'date_field': forms.DateInput(attrs={'format': 'yyyy-mm-dd','type':'date'}),
}
```