# Django HTML datetime picker

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I would like to know, what are the alternatives to show a datetime picker. I use bootstrap and Django.

I need to pick month:day and then hour:minute. There have to be two buttons: one is the start date, the second is the end date.

The end date cannot be earlier than the start date.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is that in the admin side or on the front end?

anyway you should take a look at :

https://github.com/pbucher/django-bootstrap-datepicker

it's a little bit tricky because what are you trying to achieve is in between js and django.

also check an old topic:
[How to use the bootstrap-datepicker in Django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148125/how-to-use-the-bootstrap-datepicker-in-django-app)

Comment: On the frond end. I'll take a look at both links.

Comment: I've seen this: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. There is some other good solution?

Comment: what would be a good solution for your case? The datepicker as far I have seen them before in some projects that I've done, it was a lot verbose and hard to implement "an easy way". The fact is that you have to juggle between JS and the views, and yes I know, is not easy at all and it take a lot of time.